# jQuery - Replacing HTML element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I want to replace a button with an input field, where the user enters something and presses the enter button. After that, the button from the beginning should appear again. My script works so far but I can't repeat this once it finished.

**Update:** The button should also  appear again, if the input field is shown but the user don't want to enter anything and clicks somewhere else.

The code:

```
<button id="createButton">Create item</button>

/* 
     jquery stuff
*/

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#createButton').click(function( event ) {
                $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="buttonInput" placeholder="e.g. books, movies" autofocus>');  
            });


            $(this).on('keypress', function (event) {
                if(event.which == '13'){ // If enter button is pressed
                    alert('You entered something');

                    $('#buttonInput').replaceWith('<button id="createButton">Create item</button>');
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

**Update 2:** I updated the code with hide() and show() to get the same result. But how can I let the input disappear, if the user clicks somewhere inside the body, without redundancy?

The new code:

```
<button id="createButton">Create item</button>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="e.g. books, movies" autofocus>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#input').hide();

        $(document).on('click', '#createButton', function (event) {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#input').show().focus();
        });

        $('#input').on('keypress', function (event) {
            if (event.which == '13') { // if enter button is pressed
                $(this).hide().val('');
                $('#createButton').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers say, you're replacing the element (`createButton`), which means the `click` handler is no longer bound.

You can either re-bind, or bind to the parent element, with the `#createButton` selector using `on`.

```
$(document).on('click','#createButton', function( event ) {
    ...
});
```

Don't actually use `document` - use whatever the parent element is, which doesn't get replace (a `div`, perhaps?)

Replacing DOM elements is a bad approach though -- you'd be better off leaving the elements on the page, and using `show` and `hide`.

http://jsfiddle.net/v03j8bns/

**Updated Answer**

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/v03j8bns/3/) showing the `show`/`hide`/ approach. To handle:

> The button should also appear again, if the input field is shown but the user don't want to enter anything and clicks somewhere else.

When the button is clicked, I call `focus()` on the textbox. I've also hooked up a `blur()` event handler, so if the user clicks/tabs out, then it'll hide the textbox and show the button.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. The show-hide-approach seems much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the click event to newly created button again:

```js
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#createButton').click(function (event) {
               $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="buttonInput" placeholder="e.g. books, movies" autofocus>');
           });


           $(this).on('keypress', function (event) {
               if (event.which == '13') { // If enter button pressed
                   //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
                   alert('You entered something');

                   $('#buttonInput').replaceWith('<button id="createButton">Create item</button>');
               }

               $('#createButton').bind('click', function (event) {
                   $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="buttonInput" placeholder="e.g. books, movies" autofocus>');
               });
           });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you replace DOM elements. It means that your new element button no longer has click handler.

I would recommend you to use something like `show/hide` or use jQuery delegate `on/bind` for handling click.

Answer (score 0):

When you're changing DOM on the fly and want to automatically assign listeners to elements that may or may not exist at certain points of time, you need to use [delegated event listeners](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click', '#createButton', function () { ... });
$(document).on('click', '#buttonInput', function () { ... });
```

These handlers will work however you scramble the DOM.